# Excel - how to make a full column autosum

Tags: microsoft-excel, column

I need in column D the total of column A, B, and C that in D1 i should have =SUM(A1:C1) in D2 I should have =SUM(A2:C2) etc. and it should continue the whole column by it self
Thanks!!
M.K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fill handle.

1. Type in cell D1: =SUM(A1:C1)
2. Press Ctrl+Enter (which keeps you in the same cell)
3. There is a little green box (called the fill handle) in the corner of the cell. Double-click that box (or drag down as far as you want).

That will make D2: =SUM(A2:C2) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dave. Here is a .gif for clarity:

[image]